# Cannot find module "bundle.js"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, webpack

I have a strange problem.... (Please, ignore my bad English :v)

I'm making app using HTML/CSS and js with jQuery. I'm using webpack too. I was using webpack-dev-server command since today - everything was working perfect. I wanted to generate single file - "bundle.js" without using server, cause i wanted to open app at another pc, without webpack.

[That's how game looks like when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdMxW.jpg)

When I changed config in package.json from:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server ./src/scrable.js"
```

To:

```
"start": "webpack ./src/scrable.js ./bundle.js"
```

I don't have any errors in my CMD console, when I typed "npm start".

But, when I opened my index.html file I saw in "source" mode that I have one error, which means that browser 'Cannot find module "bundle.js"'.

App is working, but not like it should - elements react for clicks, they're running some functions, but... just look at this:

[That's how game looks like when it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P462X.jpg)

Do you have any ideas?

This is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "jstest_",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "scrable.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack ./src/scrable.js ./bundle.js"
      
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

And this is my webpack.config.js file

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./src/scrable.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Why did you change the config if it was working as expected before?

Comment: Change `"webpack ./src/scrable.js ./bundle.js"` to `"webpack ./src/scrable.js bundle.js"`

Comment: I changed it, cause using webpack-dev-server i can run my app only using "npm start" thru the CMD console. To run app without node, i need to have generated "bundle.js" file, which have all scripts included.

Your solution helped me in a half :D I used "./bundle.js" to generate the file, then i changed it to "bundle.js", i edited some script to "tell" node that i did something in file, and he should regenerate it, and then run "npm start". I's working now, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that helped you (for the half) :-)